# DB2 use C and C++ host variable arrays

Tags: c++, sql, c, db2

I'm attempting to insert multiple rows into a DB2 database using c / c++ code like this:

```
EXEX SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
     char inputArrayChar1 [3][10];
     char inputArrayChar2 [3][10];
     char inputArrayChar3 [3][10];
EXEX SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
  sprintf(inputArrayChar1[i] , "column1Data%d" , i + 1);
  sprintf(inputArrayChar2[i] , "column2Data%d" , i + 1);
  sprintf(inputArrayChar3[i] , "column3Data%d" , i + 1);
}

EXEC SQL INSERT INTO TABLETEST (COLUMN1 , COLUMN2 , COLUMN3)
             VALUES(:inputArrayChar1 , :inputArrayChar2 ,inputArrayChar3);
```

run process DB result : only 1 row data , other 2 rows data not insert to DB.

Can anyone explain what could account for this?

I have inquiries to 1 case , need add ROWS syntax　code like this:

```
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO TABLETEST (COLUMN1 , COLUMN2 , COLUMN3)
      3 ROWS VALUES(:inputArrayChar1 , :inputArrayChar2 ,inputArrayChar3);
```

but use this syntax , Compiler issue is SQL0104N message "An unexpected token '3 ROWS' ....."

Can anyone explain what could account for this? Or I need add  Environment variable to db ? or add Environment variable to Compiler Environment ?

thanks.

Comment: There's only one INSERT operation, so you should only expect one row of data to be inserted.  If you want the same data inserted three times, then you're violating the primary key constraint (or would be if you had one).  However, you could loop three times: `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { EXEC SQL …; }` laid out over multiple lines.  You can't invent SQL syntax on the fly and expect the DBMS to know what you mean.  You have to follow the rules laid out in the manual.  You probably need the values clause you show to use `VALUES(:inputArrayChar1[0], …)`.

Comment: Given that it is DB2, you can probably use `INSERT INTO TableTest(…) VALUES(:inputArrayChar1[0], :inputArrayChar2[0], :inputArrayChar[0]), VALUES(:inputArrayChar1[1], :inputArrayChar2[1], :inputArrayChar[1]), VALUES(:inputArrayChar1[2], :inputArrayChar2[2], :inputArrayChar[2]);`, but that restricts you to exactly three entries.  A loop is more flexible.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler , Thank you for your explanation.

But , I want use host variable arrays method insert into db.

I am reference IBM db2 doc . 
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.embed.doc/doc/c0059085.html

this link method use char two dimensional array and only insere into syntax input data.

Comment: PS . TABLE key is COLUMN1 , 3 rows COLUMN1 data is different.